# JSP to use data of the current user

Tags: mysql, database, jsp, session, web

So what I am trying to do is to let another JSP to get the information of the user that just logged in (e.g. to only show information of that particular user that has just logged in instead of showing everything from the database, something that has the same meaning of SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username= current user). Anyway, below is my code, thanks a lot!

```
<%  
    String userId = request.getParameter("user_id");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
%>
<jsp:useBean id="db" class="ecom.DBConnection" scope="session" />
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="ecom.UserInfo" scope="session" />
<%
Connection conn = db.getConnection(); 

PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "select * from USERS where user_id=? and password=?");

pstmt.setString(1, userId);
pstmt.setString(2, pwd);    

ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();    


/* Comment  
    Set the user bean properties if login is successful */
if (rs.next()) {
    user.setLoggedIn(true);
    user.setUserId(rs.getString("user_id"));

} else {
    user.setLoggedIn(false);
}   

rs.close();
pstmt.close();


/* Comment 
    Forward the request to "home.jsp" if login is successful,
    otherwise forward to "error.jsp". */
String forwardURL = null;   
if (user.isLoggedIn()) {
    forwardURL = "home.jsp";
} else {
    forwardURL = "error.jsp";
} 
%>

<jsp:forward page="<%= forwardURL %>" />
```

And here's the page I am working on (Setting.jsp)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>


<jsp:useBean id="user" class="ecom.UserInfo" scope="session" />

<c:if test='${not user.loggedIn}'>
 <jsp:forward page='error.jsp'/>
</c:if>


<html>

<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<title>Jonathan's Auction Site</title>
</head>


<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0"    topmargin="0" bottommargin="0">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#000000">Jonathan's Auction Site</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#cccccc" height="18" class="menu">
        <font color="#ffffff">|</font> <B><a class="menu" href="home.jsp">Home</a></B>
        <font color="#ffffff">|</font> <B><a class="menu" href="register.jsp">Register</a></B>
        <font color="#ffffff">|</font> <B><a class="menu" href="Post.jsp">Post Items</a></B>
        <font color="#ffffff">|</font> <B><a class="menu" href="browseItems.jsp">Browse Items</a></B>
        <font color="#ffffff">|</font> <B><a class="menu" href="manageItems.jsp">Manage Items</a></B>
        <font color="#ffffff">|</font> <B><a class="menu" href="setting.jsp">Account Settings</a></B>
        <font color="#ffffff">|</font> <B><a class="menu" href="logout.jsp">Logout</a></B>
        <font color="#ffffff">|</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<%@ taglib prefix='sql' uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql' %>

<sql:setDataSource 
        driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
        url='jdbc:mysql://************'
        user='USER'
        password='Password'
        var='030'
        scope='session'
/>      


<%
String userId = request.getParameter("user_id");
%>

<sql:query dataSource='${030}' var='USERS'>
SELECT * FROM USERS
</sql:query>


<table width="63%" border="0">
  <tr> 
    <td width="16%" height="46">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="73%" height="46"> 
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
    <td width="11%" height="46">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>


<c:forEach var='USERS' items='${USERS.rows}'>

  <tr> 
    <td width="16%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="73%"> 
        <table width="352" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3>${USERS.user_id}</h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
      </table>
      </form>   
    </td>
    <td width="11%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td width="16%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="73%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="11%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

</c:forEach>


  <tr> 
    <td width="16%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="73%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="11%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td width="16%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="73%" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="11%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>

</html>
```

(Right now it displays all usernames on the database, but I only want the one same as the one logged in)

Comment: Is there a question in there? what is the problem?

Comment: basically i can use the above code to allow users that are registered in the database to login to my webpage and my other jsp pages can maintain the login info until user logs out. However for another page where it is only to display the information of the current user, how can I retrieve the current user name to compare and filter out other information?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to modify Setting.jsp here:

```
<sql:query dataSource='${030}' var='USERS'>
SELECT * FROM USERS
</sql:query>
```

If the only problem is that it's listing all your users instead of the one in the session, add `WHERE USER.ID = ?` (or whatever your id column is) and register it as a parameter, similar to your working JSP:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "select * from USERS where user_id=?");

pstmt.setString(1, userId);
```